# Read IDML file in Java

Tags: java, adobe, adobe-indesign, idml

I have a web application running in AIX server and the requirement is to read an IDML file, get the coordinates of each and every text in the file and write some custom information into a PDF based on the coordinates.

I have gone thru various documents and forums on how to setup or what is required to achieve this, but I am confused. I need some information on what is required from software and licensing perspective in order to achieve this requirement.

1. In order to run the java program, which can access IDML file in AIX server, do I have to buy InDesign Server license or I can extract the IDMLTools.jar from SDK and place it in my ClassPath?
2. Where do I find IDML SDK? I am unable to access IDMLToolsLib.com site?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Satish.

Comment: I meant IDMLLib.com not IDMLToolsLib.com

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your reply. I have gone thru InDesign SDK and it looks like we can use IDMLTools.jar to achieve this requirement. I hope I can use this. I am still trying and will let you know if I need any help..

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java lib IMLLib. It intends to ease the idml file exploration. I never used it myself but it seems a great tool.
Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQqd9NgH8W4
Site:
http://idmllib.com/

Comment: Hi Loic, the site is down, please can you give me alternative url, if u know? Thanks.

Comment: None that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Why not unzip the IDML and parse the resulting XML files?